# PHP navigation links work on localhost, but not on the live's server public_html

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am working on a website shared by two other people. We all need to upload it to our schools live servers.

Now instead of  rewritting navigations,and using relative path ../../../ for every single page, we decided to just use php. Here is the include for the html.

```
php include('../../php/includes/navbar.php')
```

Here is the php code for the global navbar: navbar.php

```
$base= 'http://localhost';            
echo "
<ul class=navbar>
 <li <a href='$base/index.php'> Index </a> </li>
 <li><a href='$base/src/devices/devices.php'>Devices</a></li>
 <li><a href='$base/src/howto/howto.php'>How To</a></li>
</ul>
";
```

Now the links work just fine when I use my home computer, with xampp.
But when I upload the site to my school's server, the links are broken.

By the way the website's index.php resides in the

www.cs.uml.edu/~USER_NAME/public_html/gameworld/

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have localhost hardcoded?

Comment: As a quick question, are you updating `$base` to be `http://www.cs.uml.edu/~{username}/public_html/gameworld`? Second, can you navigate to the pages by typing them directly into the browser?

Comment: See my updated answer you are missing closing `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In local your server base is

```
   $base= 'http://localhost';
```

and in server it should be

```
$base= 'http://www.cs.uml.edu/~USER_NAME/public_html/gameworld';
```

and final code

```
$base= 'http://www.cs.uml.edu/~USER_NAME/public_html/gameworld'; 
echo "
<ul class=navbar>
 <li> <a href='$base/index.php'> Index </a> </li>
 <li><a href='$base/src/devices/devices.php'>Devices</a></li>
 <li><a href='$base/src/howto/howto.php'>How To</a></li>
</ul>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the $base variable. When you put it on your website make sure it reflects the url of your website and no longer says localhost.

Answer (score 0):

`$base` should be your website URL

```
$base = 'http://www.cs.uml.edu/~USER_NAME/public_html/gameworld'
```

You are missing closing `>` of the first `<li>` element too.

```
<li <a href='$base/index.php'> Index </a> </li>
```

Comment: @Genus Added it. Not sure why your edit was rejected by some other Mod.

Comment: oops! I just noticed that.

Comment: @Shiva, its all right, they do what they like to do.